# archive groups in teams in bulk using powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to archive 200 teams in Microsoft teams which is belong to one user
using PowerShell
I find out I can archive one team using group id , like :

```
Set-TeamArchivedState -GroupId <id> -Archived:$true
```

but now I need to archive multiple teams using group id
any suggestion ?

thanks ,,

Comment: Probably `Get-Team -User someuser | Set-TeamArchivedState -Archived:$true` to set all groups belonging to the user to archived.   That's usually how these things work.

Comment: it works , thank you